# laravel create project fail via composer

Tags: php, laravel

When I type this command:

`create-project laravel/laravel blog "5.1.*"`

I get the following error message:

```
[composer\Downloader\TransportException] Content-Length mismatch
```

I am very stuck unable to create Laravel project.

Comment: May php composer create-project laravel/laravel blog --prefer-dist

Comment: Try to add   `"repositories": [    
    {    
         "type": "composer", 
         "url": "https://packagist.org"
    },
    { "packagist": false }
]`  to your composer.json

Comment: unable to find composer.json

Comment: Run `composer selfupdate`.

Comment: Now its working, Thank you so much.